# Is it possible to update a trained model in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, online-machine-learning

Is it possible, for any Python sklearn learning model, to update an already-fitted model? For example, if I have trained my model on a large set of data, is it possible to update the training by introducing new data, or does it have to be retrained every time?

Comment: Most models have to be trained from scratch. Some models have `partial_fit()` method meaning you can update it

Comment: See the duplicate thread and the [Incremental learning](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/computing.html#incremental-learning) section in the docs.